# How to edit/open or make a .c32 file?

Tags: boot, live-cd, customization, file-format

I am editing a live-CD, inside of which I found in isolinux/vesamenu.c32. I would like to look into that file. Is there any way to open and edit a .c32 file?

Answer (score 2):

### You have two options:

#### Hex edit `vesamenu.c32`

1. Open `vesamenu.c32` in a hex editor.
2. Edit it.

#### Edit the source `vesamenu.c` and recompile

1. Open `vesamenu.c` in a text editor
2. Edit it
3. Re-compile it to `vesamenu.c32`

Comment: thank you . can you suggest me a good hex  editor?

Comment: Try [Bless](http://home.gna.org/bless/)